# media query not working in mozilla

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have written media query css for  both chrome and mozilla.It works fine in chrome.but in mozilla not working

```
@media screen and (min-height:650px)
 {
  #customerspeak .flexslider .slides .customerBackground img {
  height: 100vh; 
 }
 #customerspeak .flex-direction-nav a {
   margin-top: 37%;
 }
 #customerspeak .flex-next {
  left: 62.5% !important;
 }
 #customerspeak .flex-prev {
  left: 34% !important;   
  }  
 @-moz-document url-prefix() {

   #customerspeak .flexslider .slides .customerBackground img {
   height: 100vh; 
  }
  #customerspeak .flex-direction-nav a {
   margin-top: 37%;
  }
  #customerspeak .flex-next {
  left: 62.5% !important;
 }
 #customerspeak .flex-prev {
 left: 34% !important;   
 }   
}
}
```

Comment: Is the @-moz supposed to be inside the other media query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `@-moz-document url-prefix()` first before the `@media` query.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    @media screen and (min-height:650px) {
       /* insert code here*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, your solution I have tried and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/eud4xkwd/